# Portable way to determining of printer is physical or virtual

Tags: java, silverlight, flash, printing, hardware

I need direct-to-printer functionality for my website, with the ability to distinguish a physical printer from a virtual printer (file).

Coupons.com has this functionality via a native binary which must be installed by the user. I'd prefer to avoid that.

SmartSource.com does it via Java applet:

[image: Smart Source Java Applet]

Does anybody know how this is done? I dug through that Java APIs a bit, and don't see anything that would let you determine physical vs virtual, except looking at the name (that seems prone to misidentification). It would be nice to be able to do it in Java, because I already know how to write Java applets. Failing that, is there a way to do this in Flash or Silverlight?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Well deserved bounty awarded to Jason Sperske who worked out an elegant solution. Thanks to those of you who shared ideas, as well as those who actually investigated SmartSource.com's solution (like Adrian).

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Answering your questions in reverse order: **(2)** I need to *try* to restrict printing to exactly one copy. **(1)** I need to do it for the same reason Coupons.com, SmartSource.com, and other online coupon outlets do: the manufacturers who supply these coupons don't want people to be able to easily print multiple copies of a coupon. Yes, I know: anybody with half a brain can take the physical printer's output to a photocopier, but this particular roadblock (direct-to-printer, disallowing file printers) is now standard on these other sites, so manufacturers expect it (rational or not).

Comment: So what you basically are asking is "how can I build a useless toll-gate like http://failblog.org/2008/03/13/toll-gate-fail/ in Java/flash/silverlight"? I feel sorry both for you receiving such a meaningless task and for your employer's ignorance and lack of common sense. Any chance that you will be able to educate them?

Comment: My employer is trying to sign on manufacturers to supply coupons, which in turn will allows us to acquire more venture capital. The manufacturers are the ones requesting this speed bump, and we're not in a position to tell them it's stupid; everybody else they work with gives it to them. **|** From a technical perspective, I don't really care *why*, I just want to know *how*. SmartSource.com does it in Java, so it must be possible. How?

Comment: @hlovdal: easily circumventable hurdles aren't always useless. If you stop 50% of the people from printing multiple times (because it's just no longer as easy), then that can be a big, important step.

Comment: Have you considered decompiling a Java applet that has this functionality?

Comment: @Gabe: Yes. In fact, I decompiled SmartSource.com's applet (shhhhh...) However, (1) the decompilers I tried choked on sections dealing with the printer API, showing only raw JVM instructions, and (2) the applet's strings are encrypted, so it's hard to make sense of what's left. **|** I tried running it locally, so perhaps I could step through it, but it aborted for unknown reasons. **|** I *wanted* to go down this rabbit hole further, because it's fun, but I feared it would end up deeper than I can justify to my employer ('time card: 84 hours - learning to reverse engineer applets')

Comment: Two suggestions -- get a third party to decompile that applet and tell you in general terms how it works -- the raw JVM instructions can be understood, and it must contain the code to decrypt the strings.


Or print a unique barcode on each coupon and provide your customers with a web service which allows them to ensure that each coupon is only redeemed once -- differentiate yourself from competitors who provide only security theatre by providing real security.

Comment: SmartSource.com's applet appears to "call home" with the printer name as parameter e.g. http://smartsource.com/smartsource/SmartSourceFrontController?printerName=PRINTERNAME&amp;jreVersion=1.6.0_22&amp;userId=100081872&amp;_m=ST0012AB2134CD9B56EF7778GH1C91IJA8&amp;entry=printtrack&amp;command=PrintTrackingCommand&amp;pinNumber=14968@@49846528:14968@@49846528&amp;JavaDetectId=null&amp;lookupid=14&amp;trackMode=Update&amp;printId=69755370&amp; with cookie "__utmc=83070996"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK here is what I've found so far (this is not an exhaustive test by any means, but it has been a fun problem to try and tackle).  it seems that there might be some help by looking at how the validatePage() method in the PrinterJob class works.  It seems that if a printer job is virtual than any attempt to set a page's ImageableArea will always return a value exactly equal to the default pages ImageableArea while an attempt to to the same to a real printer will return slightly smaller values (to account for the edges of the paper being held by the printer mechanics.  What helps for this problem is that if you just ask a printer for it's default characteristics before calling validate you get an optimistic result, and if you compare this to a validated response you can do a simple if test.  I've written some code for this that seems to work with the image printers and real printers I have on my desktop (again this isn't exhaustive, but it could work as a starting point)

```
import java.awt.print.*;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.attribute.Attribute;

public class DetectFilePrinter {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PrintService printer = job.getPrintService();
    System.out.println("Printer Name:"+printer.getName());

    System.out.println(printer.toString());
    PageFormat page = job.defaultPage();
    double default_width = page.getWidth();
    double default_height = page.getHeight();

    Paper paper = new Paper();
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    page.setPaper(paper);

    PageFormat fixed_page = job.validatePage(page);

    double fixed_width = fixed_page.getImageableWidth();
    double fixed_height = fixed_page.getImageableHeight();

    //So far all of my tested "image printers" return the same 
    //height and width after calling validatePage()
    if(default_height == fixed_height && default_width == fixed_width) {
      System.out.println("This looks like a \"image printer\"");
    } else {
      System.out.println("This looks like a \"real printer\"");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Jason, you are the man. Kudos on an extremely clever solution. Thanks for going above and beyond the call of duty.

Comment: BTW: I wrote a little [test applet](http://tetzfiles.com/work/imarket/PrinterDetect), and got a false detect on my girlfriend's machine -- Microsoft OneNote. I'll have to play around with this a bit.

Comment: Interesting, feel free to unselect my answer if you want to use the the bounty to try and get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there appear to be ways of gleaning a bit of information about the printer:

`javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterMakeAndModel` looks promising.

Disallowing file: Destinations on any printer, and printing to any printer with the word `PDF` in the printer make and model would likely cover 90% of the cases judging by [this list of virtual print software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_printer_software).  You realistically aren't going to run into false positives on the word PDF either.

If this feature isn't perfect, your client isn't likely to notice; your competitors likely also have some horrible kludge because they know just as well this feature is more "security theater" than actual security.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it very easily on Win32. There is a structure called PRINTER_INFO_2 which has a field called pPortName. You can string compare it with the string "FILE" and get all the queues which are connected to the "FILE" port. And you can similarly add in more parsing logic for detecting other virtual printers. This structure is filled up by Windows when you call GetPrinter with the printer handle. Now the question is how to do it in .NET. I saw one way which is using marshalling. I saw some code snippets in http://vbcity.com/forums/t/66183.aspx. You can also look at C# interop using pInvoke. http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/PRINTER_INFO_2.html

Hope this helps.