# How to know if the printer is a physical printer?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, printers, network-printers

In C#, how is it possible to distinguish physicals printers as opposed to virtual one (like a PDF writer).

Best case scenario i'd like to do this:

```
bool physical = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[0].IsPhysicalPrinter();

public static bool IsPhysicalPrinter(this PrinterSettings printer)
{
    //Do Some Magics
}
```

Comment: related Java question: [Portable way to determining of printer is physical or virtual](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112543/portable-way-to-determining-of-printer-is-physical-or-virtual)

Comment: Have you tried reading the registry? The relevant entries are located at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers

Comment: What should I look for in the registry? I check quickly but didn't find anything that would allow me to distinguish them with certainty.