# trying to find printer installed using c# not virtual printer such pdf printer

Tags: c#, printing

I have an application in which I need to print data when new data is received, but printing function should be ignored if no printers are installed.
i need to detect if those installed printers are not fax, PDF printer and so forth.

following is my attempt when no printers are installed.

```
public Boolean Check_Printer()
{
   foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
   {
       printersList.Add(printer);
   }

   if (!printersList.Any())
   {
       return false;

   }
   else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Printersettings.PrinterName))
   {
       return false;

   }
   else
   {
       return true;

   }
}
```

Comment: Have a look to see if the answer here (near the bottom) helps : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4de14b8-8d59-467b-a4b1-971dd340c72c/physical-device-printer-or-document-writer-printer?forum=csharpgeneral  or the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112543/portable-way-to-determining-of-printer-is-physical-or-virtual

Comment: Reformatted code